# 301 redirection whole domain to new one + few individual pages to new urls

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have olddomain.com - and I want to redirect to newdomain.com with htaccess and 301 - thats easy and working very well for me - if I am redirecting whole domain.

But on the new domain I changed few urls (now they are different then on the previous domain) and I want to redirect whole domain and few specific pages to few specific pages and I dont know how to combine this 2 conditions (redirect whole domain and redirect few specific pages).

This is working for me

```
RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ https://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

and I would like to add to the code some specific redirects like this but I dont know how to combine it together that it will be working:

```
Redirect 301 /something/ https://newdomain.com/something-changed-new/
```

Thank you in advance for a help.

Comment: Are `olddomain.com` and `newdomain.com` pointing to the same server/filesystem?

Answer (score 1):

Check this rewrites in top of your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^something\/$ https://newdomain.com/something-changed-new/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^other\/$ https://newdomain.com/something-changed-other/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^old\/$ https://newdomain.com/new/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://newdomain.com/$1 [L]
```